# insert columns that are missing in a range

Tags: sas

I've created panel data by transposing columns, based on weeks, and some of the weeks never had observations, so those weeks never showed up as columns.  Is there a reasonable way to insert the weeks that had no observations.

I need week0-week61, but currently I am missing week0, week4, week8...  It seems silly to do this by hand in excel.

Comment: Go back to the other question and use the array solution.  That one is better suited for this particular usage.

Comment: Actually, the `proc transpose` solution would give you all 62 columns also, so either way follow that answer properly and you would have them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is like this:

```
data ttt;
    input id week0 week4;
    datalines;
    1 10 20
    2 11 21
    ;

data ttt1;
    set ttt;
    array a{*} week0-week61;
run;
```